# Ethernet Magnetics CT pin shorting issue and the fix

Tags: ethernet, magnetics, phy

We have a design where a voltage mode 1GbE PHY is driving the magnetics and the link is intermittent. Upon inspection it turned out the CT pins on the primary side of magnetics are all shorted as shown in the picture. Now in order to do the rework (only for testing)  our only option is to do via drilling to remove the short but in the process we will lose the caps C4,C58,C60 and C10 from the circuit.

There are two questions:

1. Will the circuit behave as it is now due to this shorting connection?
2. If we did do the rework and remove the CT shorting which will force us to disconnect the CT caps, will the Ethernet still function?

Thx in advance

[image]

Comment: That might not be the issue. In many PHYs the CT pins are biased to same voltage. Which PHY is this?

Comment: Impossible to say as impedance on logic diagram is 0 so it depends on traces 1nH/mm

Comment: We are not sure what PHY part is used as this in a separate card. What we know is that this is a voltage mode PHY and it does not need external bias that is generally needed in a current mode PHY.